# Know if the running version of a program is the one on disk

Tags: file-management, overwrite

How can I know if the version of a program which is currently running is the one residing on disk, or if it is an older version (that may have been replaced, e.g., by an upgrade?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `lsof -p PID` and check for the "txt" field (4th column) if there is a `(deleted)` next to the file name in the last field.

On Debian, you can also use the `checkrestart` utility (but it may not catch all cases).

Comment: Note that lsof just does the equivalent of `readlink /proc/PID/exe`, it's a bit of a heavyweight tool for reading that information.

Comment: So is it just "an exexutable with the same name/path still exists"?

Comment: No, the important case is to distinguish the case where there is an executable with the same name/path but it is not the version of the program which is currently running.